# Jenkins maven build dependent projects?

Tags: build, jenkins, agile

I have a project with multiple modules say "Application A" and "Application B" modules (these are separate module with its own pom file but are not related to each other).

In the dev cycle, each of these modules have its own feature branch. Say,

```
 Application A --- Master
                  \
                   - Feature 1

 Application B --- Master
                  \
                   - Feature 1
```

Say Application A is independent and has its own release cycle/version.

Application B uses Application A as a jar. And is defined in its pom dependency.

Now, both teams are working on a feature branch say "Feature 1". What is the best way to setup Jenkins build such that, Build job for Application B is able to use the latest jar from "Feature 1" branch of Application A.

Given Feature 1 is not allowed to deploy its artifacts to maven repository.

Somehow I want the jar from Application A's Feature 1 branch to be supplied as the correct dependency for Application B?

Comment: Are there many such feature branches being developed concurrently? Do the teams developing each branch have control over the poms and Jenkins configs for their respective branches? Are your maven repos that vend production artifacts separate from the repos that vend dev artifacts?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you allow feature1 to deploy to the maven repository?

If it's about not mixing unstable and stable code in the repo, how about setting up a second maven repository only for unstable code?

Answer (score 0):

Should you not just fix that with a new version and creating snapshots? For your new feature you create a snapshot for the upcoming specific version. (e.g. 01.01.00.001-SNAPSHOT). The master still has a different version (e.g. 01.00.00.055) and will not be bothered with this new version snapshot. Though the feature branch on your other app can use version 01.01.00.001-SNAPSHOT as a dependency.